# Label rows and columns of an ArrayPlot?

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to label the rows and columns of an ArrayPlot?

I have a somewhat large matrix, about 90x90. The rows and columns of this matrix have names. I want to plot this matrix using ArrayPlot, and I want to display labels indicating the names of the rows and columns. Ideally, column labels should be vertical, above the respective column, and row labels should be horizontal, at the side of the respective row.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
tikc1 = {r1, r2, r3};
htick = {#, Style[tikc1[[#]], 14, Bold]} & /@ Range[3];
tikc2 = {c1, c2, c3, c4};
vtick = {#, Style[Rotate[tikc2[[#]], Pi/2], Bold, Red, 14]} & /@ 
  Range[4]; ArrayPlot[{{1, 0, 0, 0.3}, {1, 1, 0, 0.3}, {1, 0, 1, 
   0.7}}, FrameTicks -> {htick, vtick, htick, vtick}]
```

[image]

Comment: @becko, check update

Comment: Almost. Only one more thing. The column labels should be rotated, otherwise they get scrambled. How can I do that?

Comment: @becko, check update 2

Answer (score 7):

```
data = RandomInteger[10, {20, 20}];

ticklabels = StringJoin /@ # & /@ RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], {2, 20, 3}];
ticklabels2 = MapAt[Rotate[#, Pi/2] &, ticklabels, {2, All}];
ticks = (MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, #] & /@ ticklabels2);
ticks2 = {{ticks[[1]], None}, {None, ticks[[2]]}};

ArrayPlot[data, FrameTicks -> ticks2]
```

[image]

For labels on all sides use

```
 ticks2 =ticks[[{1,2,1,2}]]; 
 ArrayPlot[data, FrameTicks -> ticks2]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add here how you do the simplest case i.e. 2x2 matrix with labels as in your first matrix, please, without randomisation. Also the entry could be simply numbers for the simplest case.

Comment: I am thinking how to visualise such big matrices with statistical values of sensitivity, specificity, np, pp and p here http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/240054/3017 I think some sort of graph can be more analytical to emphasize the densities and analytical statistics. However, I think those parameters are not sufficient and some sort of web should be made.